# How can I zoom in TextEdit?

Tags: text, ms-office, zoom, textedit

I am given documents from various different sources in various different formats to work with. I use TextEdit to read and make small edits to them.

TextEdit can read and edit all of the formats I need it to: Word 2003 (.doc), Word 2007 (.docx), RTF, and TXT. The problem is that it seems to only be able to zoom in on some of them:

[image]

Only .doc and .rtf allow me to zoom (via the `100%` menu at the bottom right).

**How can I zoom in on documents of all formats, including .docx and .txt, in TextEdit?**

Comment: How do you get the zoom button?

Comment: @gentmatt I see it automatically when I open a .doc or .rtf file.

Comment: I can't get it to show. I've tried to always show the scrolling bars. But that does not make that box appear.

Comment: Ha! Trying to resolve the problem of getting the zoom button, I think that I have found the solution to your problem. *Wrap to Page* does allow me to zoom in *.txt files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Format  →  Wrap to Page** or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

Comment: Awesome! No idea why it was enabled by default for some formats and not others. Thanks, this will save me a lot of headache.

Answer (score 2):

From the menu choose View > Zoom In

or

<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>.</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

In most of applications you can use shortcuts ⌘+ and ⌘- for zooming. Very easy and convenient.

However, in Textedit these are for changing font size. It may help sometimes, but keep in mind you are editing the document in this way. To avoid it, you'll have to use Wrap to Page option as gentmatt mentioned.